# How do you create a UI button to activate the "paint Vertex Color Tool" in python?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create a UI button for a python script that activates the 'Paint Vertex Color Tool' that is already available in maya under Color>Paint Vertex Color Tool. I found the following code for creating an artisan painting context which brings up a tool pallate for editing the brush but the brush creted doesn't paint anything onto the geometry.

```
cmds.artAttrPaintVertexCtx('artAttrPaintVertexCtx1')
cmds.setToolTo('artAttrPaintVertexCtx1')
```

what do I need to do (adding a 'pollcolorpervertex' node etc) to make the brush paint onto the geometry in the same way that the default tool does? (I was struggling to find tutorials online on this toppic)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this by turning on echo all commands in the script editor history to find the command that was executed when the button is pressed manually. This turned out to be:

```
PaintVertexColorTool;
```

so now I am just using

```
maya.mel.eval("PaintVertexColorTool;")
```

to execute the mel command through python.

While not the neatest solution I think it will work in this case. Anyone who can come up with a more informative answer please reply.